# Insert link to local file onto xwiki

Tags: wiki, xwiki

Hi this may apply to platforms/wikis outside of xwiki, but I am trying the embed a file by doing the following

```
[[myfile>>file://C:/users/myfile.txt]]
```

where clicking on the newly created link does nothing.

I have tried with backslashed file path too but no difference and three slashes infront of "file:"

this should be pretty straightforward....

Comment: three slashes infront of "file:" ? tried that too.. will add into question

Comment: turns out three slashes work but only as save target as and downloading into a file....but then i guess this makes sense. thanks. can you post as an answer so I can accept?

Comment: Moved comment to answer, deleted comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should be three slashes in a URI like `file:///C:/`.

After the "protocol" part, the [file URI scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme#Format) takes first a host name (which can be omitted in your case, because you are trying to access a local resource), then the path. Between host and path there is a slash. (This holds for other URI schemes, as well...)

The slash has to remain, even if the host part is omitted.